# How do i pack a video into blend file?

Tags: blend-files, sheepit

i'm using sheepit to render my project, which require for me to upload my file externally. but the problem is, i can't seems to find a solution on transferring the video into the blend file, even though i already mark the "automatically pack resource" in external data. Is this feature available? is there a solution to this? anybody found a workaround for this?

Comment: I don't think so, you can't pack the images in the Video Sequencer either

Comment: I suspect that's one for Sheepit to answer in view of moonboots' comment!

Comment: aww, so theres no way to do it?

Comment: i've found it :D

Answer (score 2):

i've found a way. you have to pack everything in the same folder as your blender file, and select relative path. It must be inside a folder. Then select the folder with your video/image and select the blender file, and then zip it. Then it can be send to sheepit(again, the video/image must be inside folder, and pick relative path on external data)

Comment: You can easily do that by first packing everything, setting relative path, then unpacking everything with the option to create your own files and folders near the .blend file. Then pack all again.

Comment: I was about to give up until suddenly found this post and saved me. Thank you for your answer. Helped a lot